# What are some effective ways to show large lists of data to users?

Tags: jquery, css, list, menu

Whether it be a drop down list, a hover menu, with sub "fly-out" menus, etc...

I have a large list of [U.S. military bases in the world](http://www.atmybase.com/Tools/AddBase) for my site. That list actually contains the bases that are not yet active on the site. The active ones appear in a hover menu when you hover over the text "Select your base [hover]" at the top.

As you can see, it's currently a menu with "fly-out" sub menus. I'm concerned that as more and more bases get activated, that menu won't support it very well.

Other than a mega-dropdown menu, I'm drawing a blank on a good way to support this. What types of effective menus out there support this scenario well? jQuery based is fine as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are good, but all make assumptions about how people are searching. Best way to think about it is: how would your user think about the base?

- Do they likely know the exact base they want? (use a text search like jquery autocomplete)
- Do they likely know roughly where it is geographically? (use a map)
- Do they know the state/country it is in by name? (use a categorized list)

Just think through how your users think, and the closest match you've ever seen, then find a way to implement that.

Comment: Hmm, in this case... the user's are expected to know the name of their base. But, they would also know it's location, and likely the state/country. The idea of the site is to support all bases, but make each base the user's "dashboard" (for lack of a better term). With U.S. military personnel being stationed at a base for 2-3 years, theoretically they'd only need to select one base consistently (maybe 2-3 if other bases are nearby). Nice answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For that much data I would go to a visual map with pinpoints for each base location - it will be more intuitive for your users to find what they are looking for, and also offer an interesting way to visualize the data.

Google Charts API offers a good starting point for creating map charts:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/new_map_charts.html

Comment: I like this idea (that link is awesome btw)!

I didn't originally go with the visual method because of the scale of things (being all over the world). Asking the visitors to know geography enough to pinpoint their base from a fairly "zoomed out" map, could be problematic. Any ideas to break that issue?

Answer (score 1):

In this case maybe a menu is not the way to go. A better idea would be to have the top level regions in the drop down, and when you click on that link you are sent to another page that has the more local bases?

Comment: I like this, or maybe even have a mega drop down for each top-level region. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good, I guess at the end of the day its what's work best for you and your users.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches. The most appropriate if you want to keep the structure you have in place is to have a multi-level drop down, so the first drop down menu would show US/Overseas and as you hover over each of these, it would show an additional menu, either Countries or States depending on which you select - this then shows the bases on that state or country.

- US

  - Alabama

    - Anniston Army Depot, AL
    - Fort Rucker, AL
    - ...
  - Alaska
  - ...
- Overseas

  - Bahrain
  - Belgium
  - ...

There is a good example of this here: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/dropdown-menu/index.html

The markup is very simple, with `<ul>`'s inside `<ul>`'s.

Comment: Is this not the approach they're is using already? Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at the site? It's clearly not - they've got a long list (well it's a list that will obviously get longer, as the OP noted). I'm talking about separating the list into a cascading multilevel list, rather than a single long list.

Comment: Thanks kieran. That is already the approach I was using (in the hover menu described). Maybe my question was clear enough though, my fault. What I intend is that, at some point (if things remain as they are now) every base you see on the long list would appear in that hover menu... I believe it could get unwieldy.

Thanks for taking the time to answer, I appreciate that.

Comment: Chad, my approach was that assuming you wish to keep that hover menu you could keep most of the list hidden, and only view it when the user selects the area they are interested in. I can't comment on the other answer but Autocomplete is a solid answer as well - the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget allows you to build a composite of date , so a base could be "US/Alabama/Fort Rucker, AL" and searching for "US", "Alabama" or "Fort Rucker" would narrow the list of results to any matches.

Comment: Kieran, good call. I'm thinking maybe a hybrid drop down, mega-menu with autocomplete filtering could be effective. Thanks!